# Connect raspberry pi with ti sensor tag - connection refused (111)

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors

I tried to connect my rapsberry pi with a TI sensor tag.

Therefore I did:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hcitool lescan
gatttool -b [bluetooth_adr] --interactive    # which was successful
connect
```

After executing the connect command I get the error: `Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)`

Can anybody help me with that? I restarted my Rapsberry Pi but it still did not work. Thank you!